# How to position inputs in equal height with Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I build [This](https://fiddle.jshell.net/roybarak/adb7tekp/1/) menu, and i can't set the left side's inputs to be in the same height as the right ones... the solution i'm thinking of is to set equal height to to input's divs and then to use flex-grow - and set field 7 to double of it's height... I've tried that and it's not working - perhaps their is a better way to do it? i've tried to do so with bootstrap also - but run into the same problem.

Html :

```
    <div class="container">

      <div class="tab-pane active" id="mes_informations">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 mes_informations_left_cont">

                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 1</p>
                  <div class="switch_div_info">


                    <div class="switch" style="border-radius:25px;">

                      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="" id="week" checked="">

                      <label for="week" class="switch-label switch-label-off male">
                        <i class="fa fa-mars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <label>
                          Homme
                        </label>
                      </label>

                      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="" id="month">
                      <label for="month" class="switch-label switch-label-on female">
                        <label>
                          Femme
                        </label> <i class="fa fa-venus" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>


                      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 2</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="societe" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 3</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="siren" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 3</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="nom_contact" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 4</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="prenom_contact" type="text">
                </div>

              </div>


              <div class="col-md-6 mes_informations_right_cont">
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 5</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="service" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 6</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="address" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp input_double">

                  <p>field 7</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="address_fac" type="text">

                  <div class="address_input_grp">
                    <input class="form-control pull-left" id="vile" type="text">
                    <input class="form-control pull-right" id="code_postal" type="text">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>field 8</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="nom_contact_fac" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
    .container {
      padding: 15px;
      height: 800px;
      width: 800px;
      background-color: #e9e9e9;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      height: 32px;
      width: 140px;
      /*margin: 20px auto;*/
      background: white;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-label {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      float: left;
      width: 58px;
      line-height: 26px;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-label label {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      color: #2b2b2b;
      display: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      position: relative;
      display: none;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-label:active {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-label-off {
      padding-left: 2px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-label-on {
      padding-right: 2px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-input {
      display: none;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
      -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -moz-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -ms-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -o-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      transition-property: color, text-shadow;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label label {
      display: block;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label-on ~ .switch-selection {
      left: 45px;
      /* Note: left: 50%; doesn't transition in WebKit */
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-selection {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: -1px;
      left: 0px;
      display: block;
      width: 105px;
      height: 36px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
      -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
      transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label .fa {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-top: 6px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.male {
      float: left;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.female {
      float: right;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.male .fa {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.female .fa {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.male label {
      left: 31px;
      top: -23px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.female label {
      right: 26px;
      top: 3px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label.female .fa {
      position: relative;
      top: -30px;
    }

    .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label .fa {
      color: rgb(73, 200, 193);
    }

    #mes_informations .cont {
      display: flex;
    }

    #mes_informations P {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.8vw;
      color: #2b2b2b;
    }

    .mes_informations_left_cont {
      min-height: 400px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: stretch;
    }

    .mes_informations_right_cont {
      min-height: 400px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: stretch;
    }

    #mes_informations .cont .left_cont > .inputs_grp,
    #mes_informations .cont .right_cont > .inputs_grp {}


    /*.left_cont > .inputs_grp, .right_cont > .inputs_grp {*/


    /*min-height: 60px;*/


    /*margin-top: 17px;*/


    /*margin-bottom: 15px;*/


    /*}*/


    /*.address_grp{
        min-height: 136px!important;
    }*/


    /*.address_input_grp{*/


    /*padding-top: 15px;*/


    /*}*/

    .address_input_grp > input {
      width: 48%;
    }

    #save_info:hover {
      background-color: #40afa9;
      outline: none;
    }

    #save_info {
      background-color: #49c8c1;
      border: 1px solid white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-size: 0.8vw;
      padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
      color: #fff;
      outline: none;
    }

    .inputs_grp > .form-control {
      border-radius: 5px!important;
    }

    .inputs_grp {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

Comment: you *can't* align flex children in different `flexbox`'s...

Comment: Thanks - perhaps their is other way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by change all inputs to inline by flexbox.

html

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="grp_wrap">

      <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>CIVILITÉ</p>
                  <div class="switch_div_info">


                    <div class="switch" style="border-radius:25px;">

                      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="" id="week" checked="">

                      <label for="week" class="switch-label switch-label-off male">
                        <i class="fa fa-mars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <label>
                          Homme
                        </label>
                      </label>

                      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="" id="month">
                      <label for="month" class="switch-label switch-label-on female">
                        <label>
                          Femme
                        </label> <i class="fa fa-venus" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>


                      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>SERVICE À FACTURER</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="service" type="text">
                </div>

    </div>
    <div class="grp_wrap">

    <div class="inputs_grp">
      <p>SOCIÉTÉ</p>
      <input class="form-control" id="societe" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="inputs_grp">
      <p>ADRESSE DE FACTURATION</p>
      <input class="form-control" id="address" type="text">
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="grp_wrap">
     <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>SIRET/SIREN</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="siren" type="text">
                </div>
      <div class="inputs_grp">

                  <p>ADRESSE</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="address_fac" type="text">


                </div>

    </div>
    <div class="grp_wrap">
    <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>PRÉNOM DU CONTACT PRINCIPAL</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="prenom_contact" type="text">
                </div>
      <div class="inputs_grp address_input_grp">
                    <input class="form-control pull-left" id="vile" type="text">
                    <input class="form-control pull-right" id="code_postal" type="text">
                  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grp_wrap">
      <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>PRÉNOM DU CONTACT PRINCIPAL</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="prenom_contact" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="inputs_grp">
                  <p>NOM DE CONTACT DE FACTURATION</p>
                  <input class="form-control" id="nom_contact_fac" type="text">
                </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
    .wrapper{
      width:80%;
    }
    .inputs_grp{
      width:48%;

      margin-bottom:15px;

    }

    .grp_wrap{
      display:flex;
    }

      .switch_div_info .switch {
              float: left;
              position: relative;
              height: 32px;
              width: 140px;
              /*margin: 20px auto;*/
              background: white;
              border-radius: 3px;
              -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-label {
              position: relative;
              z-index: 2;
              float: left;
              width: 58px;
              line-height: 26px;
              font-size: 11px;
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
              text-align: center;
              text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-label label {
              font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
              color: #2b2b2b;
              display: none;
              font-size: 12px;
              position: relative;
              display: none;
              font-weight: 100;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-label:active {
              font-weight: bold;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-label-off {
              padding-left: 2px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-label-on {
              padding-right: 2px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-input {
              display: none;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label {
              font-weight: bold;
              color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
              text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
              -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
              -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
              -ms-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
              -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
              transition: 0.15s ease-out;
              -webkit-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
              -moz-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
              -ms-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
              -o-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
              transition-property: color, text-shadow;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label label {
              display: block;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label-on ~ .switch-selection {
              left: 45px;
              /* Note: left: 50%; doesn't transition in WebKit */
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-selection {
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              top: -1px;
              left: 0px;
              display: block;
              width: 105px;
              height: 36px;
              border-radius: 3px;
              background-color: white;
              -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
              -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
              -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
              -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
              -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
              transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
              border-radius: 25px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label .fa {
              font-size: 20px;
              margin-top: 6px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.male {
              float: left;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.female {
              float: right;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.male .fa {
              float: left;
              margin-left: 5px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.female .fa {
              float: right;
              margin-right: 5px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.male label {
              left: 31px;
              top: -23px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch .switch-label.female label {
              right: 26px;
              top: 3px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label.female .fa {
              position: relative;
              top: -30px;
            }

            .switch_div_info .switch-input:checked + .switch-label .fa {
              color: rgb(73, 200, 193);
            }
```